# How can I loop through list of strings and extract certain indices that match the string?

Tags: python

I am currently working on a python script and I have a list that stores a block of comments (see below)

```
//################ 
//# [file id number] 
//################# 
//# [file name] 
//################# 
//################# 
//# {file description} 
//# {file description continues...} 
//# {file description continues...} 
//# {file description continues...} 
//################# 
//# [some more comments] 
//# [some more comments] 
//# [some more comments] 
//##################
```

Each line is its own string, and it stored in a list. I need to extract only certain blocks. For example

```
//################# 
//# [file name] 
//#################
and 
//################# 
//# [some more comments] 
//# [some more comments] 
//# [some more comments] 
//##################
```

need to be extracted. Is there a way I can loop through the list and only extract those portions? I was going to do something along the lines of
for i in list:
if (i == "//####... "):
....
The only problem with doing this is that there can be an arbitrary number of hashtags in each line, so i cannot hard code that, and there are multiple lines that have similar properties which means that the loop would be grabbing more then I need. Any help would be great!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the specific criteria for how to determine which blocks to extract?

Comment: You can check if a line is a "separating" line with `line.startswith("//#")`

Comment: It is a script that will go through various files and find the file header that matches this pattern. However, I need to then extract only portions of the file header. The caveat to this is that, number of spaces between the slashes and first hashtag could be zero ("//##.."), one ("// ##.."), or even two ("// ##..."). Would the "startswith()" function work to match the variations?

Comment: The other issue is to distinguish the sections. Given the case that we can use regexp to match each line, for example something like `re.match(r"\/\/(\s)*(#)+(\w|\d)+", line)`, so if match you keep the line, then you should have something else to determine whether the section is correct or not